# Byzantium related homework required for pool operators and developers

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools, hardforks

Is there a summary of what code and/or configuration changes need to be implemented by mining pools and associated code to properly support the upcoming hard-fork? Do packages like [ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/ethash) need to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

One important note for that is to find on the [Ethereum Blog:](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/09/14/geth-1-7-megara/)

> Furthermore, we’d like to emphasize that the upgraded database cannot
> be used by previous versions of Geth. Our recommendation for
> production users it to sync from scratch with Geth 1.7.0, and leave
> the old database backed up until you confirm that the new release
> works correctly for all your use cases.

EDIT: This is, of course, only relevant for Geth users - you have to do this update with it's implications/consequences. No problems here for me, though.